# Do html redirect based on header request

Tags: javascript, html, json, github-pages

I have near zero html and/or javascript experience and I'm finding so little information on this topic that I suspect I've got a fundamental misunderstanding on what I'm trying to do. But hey, software developers are somehow fungible so this ended up on my plate.

I've got a git project that includes several files. It looks like this:
git repo:

- index.html
- my_data.json
- my_data.html
- .github/workflows

  - some_workflow.yaml
- some_folder

  - some_other_file.json

I want to publish this on github-pages, which expects the page to be at index.html. When a user does a request to the github-pages url the files that get returned should be based off the request header that the user uses.

For example:

- Navigating to the webpage *http://my-org.github.io/my-project* in a
  web browser would end up at the *index.html* file and should be
  redirected to *my_data.html*.
- `curl -H "Accept: application/json" "http://my-org.github.io/my-project"` should return the *my_data.json*
  file.
- A real nice bonus would be if I could navigate to *http://my-org.github.io/my-project.json* and get the json file

Redirecting to the my_data.html file by setting up a meta `<http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='./my_data.html'">` seems pretty standard but I can't figure out how to do the json part. Most tutorials specify what content negototiation is but then get all hand-wavey at the implementation or refer to API frameworks that have it all baked in.
Is there some kind of javascript if statement I could use to handle the TWO mime-types I expect to handle?

Comment: Why are you asking for an HTML or JS solution when you want to handle requests made by CURL? What you need is a server-side script.

Comment: What's wrong with `curl "http://my-org.github.io/my-project/my_data.json"`?

Comment: @Quentin the remaining of your answer was useful though, most notabily the part on github-pages (if that's correct). IMO, you should undelete and focus on that point.

Comment: Most web servers are capable of doing this, just you need to be allowed to use your own configuration files, which is not the case on GitHub Pages. In case of Apache, you could do the magic in a `.htaccess` file for example.

Comment: It looks like some tools exist to replace the .htaccess file with redirects built when the jekyll page generator is called: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from

Comment: @RedM jekyll creates server-agnostic, static content. From linked page, 2nd paragraph: *Redirects are performed by serving an HTML file with an HTTP-REFRESH meta tag which points to your destination. No .htaccess file, nginx conf, xml file, or anything else will be generated. It simply creates HTML files.*

Comment: That does seem to be the case. It's starting to look like the current requirements aren't workable with github pages. So I either need to just go directly to my_project/my_data.json or use a webserver that can handle content negotiation.